# why does it diplay "onclick" is not extensible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make simple click counter but this isn't working

```
let i = 0;
let counter = <button>{i}</button>;

counter.onclick = () => {
  i++;
  ReactDOM.render(
  counter,
  document.getElementById('root')
  );
};
```

when i run it it given this error message

```
Error in /~/index.js (12:1)
can't define property "onclick": Object is not extensible
```

any help would be appreciated I am just starting out with reactjs
thank you

Comment: reactjs sintax is a little diffrent from normal javascript , in react `onclick` becomes `onClick`

Comment: @AndriNic it's still not working

Comment: because you are mixing javascript and jsx, check here https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: thank you for your help @AndriNic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems here:

- `onclick` is a property of DOM elements, not JSX elements. You assign event handlers to JSX elements using [camelCase props](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).
- You use `ReactDOM.render()` for the initial render of your app; not to trigger updates, you trigger updates by *changing the state*.
- You need to store the data that you are changing in your state, not in a loose variable.

For example:

```js
const App = () => {
   const [i, setI] = React.useState(0);
   const increment = () => setI(i + 1);

   return <button onClick={increment}>{i}</button>
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    
<div id="root"></div>
```

You're missing so many React fundamentals that you should probably [go back to an introductory tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/React_getting_started).

Comment: thank you very much for detailed explanation yeah i tried to rush but i didn't knew syntax were so different thank you again